# RealmSwift with enum list

Tags: swift, realm

I have an enum with some strings case

```
public enum UserPermission: String, Decodable {
    case userManagement = "USER_MANAGEMENT"
    case contactManagement = "CONTACT_MANAGEMENT"
    case userV2 = "USER_V2.1"
}

@objcMembers final public class MyModel: Object, Decodable {

    public var permissionCollection = List<UserPermission>()

    public dynamic var rawRole: String? = nil

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case permissionCollection = "permission_collection"
    }

    convenience public init(permissionCollection: String) {
        self.init()
        self.permissionCollection = permissionCollection
    }

    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let rawRermissionCollection = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .permissionCollection)
        self.init(permissionCollection: permissionCollection)
    }

}
```

I have an error `Type 'UserPermission' does not conform to protocol 'RealmCollectionValue'`

In the data model I need to store the enum as a list using realm. Have someone to know how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm's `List` can only store elements that are either `Object` subclasses or one of the supported property types of Realm (such as `Int`, `String`, etc.). Realm doesn't support storing `enum` values, so you cannot store them in a `List` either.

One alternative is to store the `rawValue` of your `enum`, since it has a `rawValue` of type `String`, which can be stored in Realm.

Answer (score 0):

As of Realm 3.x you can use Int-based enums (apparently, by side-effect).

As of Realm 4.1 you can use any RawRepresentable enum (e.g. Int, Float, String) by complying with the "RealmEnum" protocol. [Details in the pull request](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/6343)

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160484/1324) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)